# Javascript display = 'block'

Tags: javascript, html-table, row

I have some code that shows a tables row when something is clicked.  So, the row has it's style attribute disabled, see below:

**HTML**

```
<tr id='Asset' class='rrtr' style='display:none;'>
```

The user clicks and fires the Javascript, which works fine:

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("Asset").style.display = 'block';
```

However, the style of the row isn't in line with rest even though it's class attributes are set to 'rrtr' like the rest.

If I turn off 'display:none;' on the row and run it showing, the format is fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For best compatibility, set

```
document.getElementById("Asset").style.display = '';
```

Internet Explorer 7 and lower do not support `table-row` as a value for `display`.  Alternatively– and, arguably, a better idea is to – set a class for the row and remove/change it using JS:

```
<tr id='Asset' class='rrtr rrtr-hidden'>
<!-- .rrtr-hidden { display: none; } -->
```

```
// Remove class `.rrtr-hidden`
document.getElementById("Asset").className = 'rrtr';
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `block`, you should set the display value to `table-row`.

Answer (score 1):

set it to `table-row` or to `""`

Answer (score 0):

I hide and show table rows by adding/removing a class name called 'hide'.  This approach has the advantage of being able to hide/show any element without knowing or caring what its normal display style is.  With table rows, that's probably a non-issue, but with other elements, you may one day wish to change from `block` to `inline` for example.  If you use a class to hide elements, you don't have to change your javascript.

In your CSS:

```
.hide {
   display:none;
}
```

And in javascript,

```
function hasClass(ele, cls) {
    if( ele != null && ele.className != null ) {
      return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)'));
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}

function addClass(ele, cls) {
    if (! hasClass(ele, cls)) {
      ele.className += " " + cls;
    }
}

function removeClass(ele, cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele, cls)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + cls + '(\\s|$)');
        ele.className = ele.className.replace(reg, '');
    }
}
```

That JS came from someone else on SO, but unfortunately I forgot to save a link.

So to hide an element `addClass( document.getElementById('Asset'), 'hide' )`  and `removeClass` to show it.

*EDIT*: I missed Andy's answer somehow.  It does essentially the same thing, however, these addClass & removeClass methods are a little more robust than modifying element.className "manually".